# Ubuntu 20.04.1 cannot setup 3rd monitor

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, intel

I have latest Linux kernel and Ubuntu 20.04

```
Linux max-work 5.7.0-050700-generic #202006082127 SMP Mon Jun 8 21:30:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Have no Discrete GPU.

My CPU (for which I'm trying to setup 3rd monitor) is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400, which does support 3 monitors as per intel official docs: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97147/intel-core-i5-7400-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html

I have 3 1920*1080 monitors, any 2 of them are working perfectly fine with each other.
Connectors are DVI, VGA and HDMI.

When I connect 3rd monitor, one of them gets disconnected and when I try to manually enable it I have the following message in settings:
[Message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLtOJ.png). (Changes Cannot be Applies. This could be due to hardware limitations).

Of what limitations does Ubuntu says, as CPU is clearly supporting 3 monitors, and each of them individually are working fine?

Comment: What is the motherboard that you are using?  Also, there is a note below about the graphics video support  `‡ This feature may not be available on all computing systems. Please check with the system vendor to determine if your system delivers this feature, or reference the system specifications (motherboard, processor, chipset, power supply, HDD, graphics controller, memory, BIOS, drivers, virtual machine monitor-VMM, platform software, and/or operating system) for feature compatibility. Functionality, performance, and other benefits of this feature may vary depending on system configuration.`

Comment: Does your motherboard actually have three discrete ports for displays?  What is the make/model of your motherboard?

Comment: @Terrance its ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. H110M-R  Rev X.0x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've indicated in comments that your motherboard uses the H110 chipset.

[The Intel H110 chipset only supports two displays at a time](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/90590/intel-h110-chipset.html) using the integrated GPU.

You will not be able to connect three displays at a time with your current hardware.

Comment: So the only way is to connect discrete GPU?

Comment: Yes, or get another motherboard with a more feature-rich chipset.  It would probably be more cost effective and easier to get an inexpensive GPU.  Make sure that it has at least 3 ports compatible with your displays.